# Jquery - get the name of an array item in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do you reference the name of an array within an array?

```
var jon_count = [0,6,7,9]
var sue_count = [9,7,6,8]
var rob_count = [7,8,6,3]
var name_list = {jon_count, sue_count, rob_count}
```

I'm trying to get the name of each variable within the "name_list" not the values of each item.

```
$.each(name_list, function (index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(ind, obj) {
       console.log(value[ind]);
    });
});
```

I know that's garbage, I want to see:

> jon_count
> sue_count
> rob_count

But I keep getting the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the index variable:

```
$.each(name_list, function (index, value) {
  alert(index);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/6gv4aqcb/3/).

Comment: Thanks Steve. This worked. Is there a way to use this information to dynamically reference this, let's say in a loop like where I only have the first name `tmname = index.toLowerCase();
window[tmname + "_count"][0]`
the problem here is that I'm getting an error on the index of the 0.

Comment: Oh, I found it. I have to reference the the first array and index that within the index (if that make sense) - I used: name_list[ thename ][0].

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this:

```
var name_list = {jon_count:"item 1", sue_count:"item 2", rob_count:"item 3"} 
var keys = Object.keys(name_list)
keys.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item)
})
```